# Dropbox symlinks trouble

Tags: sync, dropbox, symbolic-link

I have a few dozen symlinked folders, which recently stopped working. I tried to do what dropbox suggested: delete the symlinks and move the folders itself into dropbox. Unfortunately dropbox refuses to sync these folders: it gets stuck and says "Can't sync [blah.pdf]" (with no further explanation)!

To explain what I did in more detail: say the symlinked folder was called ABC. Then I deleted the symlink 'ABC' and the 'ABC (Symlink Backup Copy)' folder in my dropbox web account. I then moved folder ABC from its original location into dropbox.

For some reason if I renamed folder ABC inside dropbox (e.g. ABC2) then files sync as normal. But I really want to keep the original name!

(I am using Mac OSX 10.13 and also occasionally an ipad with an older ios. I didn't symlink any of the OSX system folders, just folders I created in ~.)

Comment: OK, unlinking dropbox and relinking solved this issue. I wasted a number of hours with this whole symlinks issue...

Comment: You should convert your comment into an answer ...